# L1 and L2 regularization and L1 and L2 space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, statistics, soft-question

I am looking to characterize the difference of the function obtained in the solution process of $L^1$ and $L^2$ regularization. It is known that $L^1$  regularization gives sparse solutions. In $L^2$  regularization the error is distributed in the whole function and in $L^1$  it may not be. My question is there a relation between the functions and the $L^1$, $L^2$ space?